# Better ways to write a Python function to return highest value corresponding to a given input after comparing a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, optimization

I have a list of dictionaries as below,

```
test = [{'a':100, 'b':1, 'd':3.2},
    {'a':200, 'b':5, 'd':8.75},
    {'a':500, 'b':2, 'd':6.67},
    {'a':150, 'b':7, 'd':3.86},
    {'a':425, 'b':2, 'd':7.72},
    {'a':424, 'b':2, 'd':7.72}]
```

Given a 'b' value, I need to find the maximum value of 'd' and extract the corresponding value of 'a' in that dictionary. If there's a tie, then take the highest value of 'a'. e.g. {a:424, b:2, d:7.72} and {a:424, b:2, d:7.72} has b = 2 and their corresponding d values are equal. In that case, I return a = 425.

Following code runs alright. However, I would like to know possible ways to optimise this or to use an anonymous function (lambda) to solve this.

```
def gerMaxA(bValue):
  temporary_d = -999.99
  temporary_a = 0
  for i in test:
      if i['b'] == bValue:
          if i['d'] > temporary_d:
              temporary_a = i['a']
              temporary_d = i['d']
          elif i['d'] == temporary_d:
              if i['a'] >= temporary_a:
                  temporary_a = i['a']
  ans = (temporary_a, temporary_d)
  return ans
```

Appreciate any insights.

Comment: "If there's a tie, then take the highest value of 'a'." Please read https://0.30000000000000004.com/ .

Comment: Why would you want to use an anonymous function to solve it? What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I would like to know possible ways to optimise this or to use an anonymous function (lambda) to solve this.

"Optimise" is a red herring - you cannot simple "optimise" something in a void, you must optimise it *for* some quality (speed, memory usage, etc.)

Instead, I will show how to make the code simpler and more elegant. This is theoretically off-topic for Stack Overflow, but IMX the system doesn't work very well if I try to send people elsewhere.

> Given a 'b' value

This means that we will be selecting elements of the list that meet a condition (i.e., the `'b'` value matches a target). Another word for this is *filtering*; while Python does have a built-in `filter` function, it is normally cleaner and more Pythonic to use a *comprehension* or *generator expression* for this purpose. Since we will be doing further processing on the results, we shouldn't choose yet.

> I need to find the maximum value of 'd'

More accurately: you see the *element which has* the maximum value for `'d'`. Or, as we like to think of it in the Python world, the *maximum element, keyed by* `'d'`. This is built-in, using the `max` function. Since we will feed data directly to this function, we don't care about building up a container, so we will choose a *generator expression* for the first step.

The first step looks like this, and means exactly what it says, read left to right:

```
(element for element in test if element['b'] == b_value)
```

"A generator (`()`) producing: the `element`, `for` each `element` found `in test`, but only including it `if` the `element`'s `['b']` value is `== b_value`".

In the second step, we wrap the `max` call around that, and supply the appropriate `key` function. This is, indeed, where we could use `lambda`:

```
max(
    (element for element in test if element['b'] == b_value),
    key=lambda element:(element['d'], element['a'])
)
```

The `lambda` here is a function that transforms a given `element` into that pair of values; `max` will then compare the filtered dicts according to what value is produced by that `lambda` for each.

Alternately, we could use a named function - lambdas are *the same thing*, just without a name and with limits on what can be done within them:

```
def my_key(element):
    return element['d'], element['a']

# and then we do
max((element for element in test if element['b'] == b_value), key=my_key)
```

Or we could use the standard library:

```
from operator import itemgetter
max((element for element in test if element['b'] == b_value), key=itemgetter('d', 'a'))
```

---

The last step, of course, is simply to extract the `['a']` value from the `max` result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that uses built-ins:

```
In [1]: from operator import itemgetter

In [2]: def max_a_value(b_value, data):
   ...:     matching_values = (d for d in data if d['b'] == b_value)
   ...:     return max(matching_values, key=itemgetter('d','a'))['a']
   ...:

In [3]: test = [{"a":100, "b":1, "d":3.2},
   ...:         {"a":200, "b":5, "d":8.75},
   ...:         {"a":500, "b":2, "d":6.67},
   ...:         {"a":150, "b":7, "d":3.86},
   ...:         {"a":425, "b":2, "d":7.72},
   ...:         {"a":424, "b":2, "d":7.72}]

In [4]: max_a_value(2, test)
Out[4]: 425
```

Note, this isn't more algorithmically efficient. Both are O(N)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can optimize this.  With the given specifications, there is no reason to retain inferior entries.  There is also no particular reason to keep this as a list of dictionaries.  Instead, make this a simple data frame or reference table.  The key is the 'b' value; the value is the desired 'a' value.

Make one pass over your data to convert to a single dict:

```
test = [ {
    1: 100,
    2: 425,
    5: 200,
    7: 150 } ]
```

There's your better data storage; you've already managed one version of conversion logic.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to check this. I don't know if it is more efficient but at least looks pythonic:

```
def gerMaxA(bValue):
    dict = {i:x['d'] for i, x in enumerate(test) if x['b']== bValue}
    idx = max(dict, key=dict.get)
    max_d = test[idx]['d']
    dict_a = {k :test[k]['a'] for k in dict.keys() if dict[k] == max_d}
    idx_a = max(dict_a, key = dict_a.get)
    return test[idx_a]['a'], test[idx]['d']
```

The last three lines of code make sure that it'll take the greater 'a' value in the case there were many of them.